# Can Ubuntu Touch be installed on a HTC Jetstream Tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is it possible to install Ubuntu Touch or any other Linux OS on an HTC Jetstream tablet? It currently runs Android Honeycomb 3.1, and is useless nowadays.

If yes, how would I install it?

Answer (score 0):

No. The list of officially supported, WIP, and abandoned devices is here: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/devices/